# Training with mixed-precision using the tensorflow estimator api

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

Does anyone has experience with mixed-precision training using the tensorflow estimator api?

I tried casting my inputs to tf.float16 and the results of the network back to tf.float32. For scaling the loss I used tf.contrib.mixed_precision.LossScaleOptimizer.

The error messages I get are relatively uninformative: "Tried to convert 'x' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported",

Comment: The error message seems very informative. `x` contains `None` values, which are not supported in the conversion to a tensor. Either `x` is erroneously getting `None`s as values (in which case you need to locate the error producing this), or this is expected but you need to sanitise the data before converting it to a tensor.

Comment: It is clear for me what the specific error means, but not why it occurs and how to avoid it. When removing the tf.contrib.mixed_precision.LossScaleOptimizer decorator. Everything works fine except I get an underflow due to casting to tf.float16 after a few iterations. After removing the casts training works as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue: I used tf.get_variable to store the learning rate. This variable has no gradient. Normal optimizers do not care, but tf.contrib.mixed_precision.LossScaleOptimizer crashes. Therefore, make sure these variables are not added to tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES.